# mongodb security for content in journal

Tags: mongodb, security, journal, journaling

I want to delete any trace of a particular database item e.g. deleting a user message from a Messages collection. I am trying to find out how can I do cleanup  the corresponding journal entries so no one can recreate the item. I don't want to disable journaling for this purpose if possible. Having a short journaling cycling window (journal cleans itself after x time) might be an option...

I tried searching amongst existing documents and responses, but might have missed something. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem with a short window is that you might as well just turn off journaling altogether tbh

Comment: I agree. I don't prefer that option either. I was thinking if there is no other way, probably I can set some option like 1 hour old journal only. This way I still get the advantage of abrupt disconnection for mongo to recover from the general, but any deleted items don't stay for more than 1 hour (or 1 day even). I hope people have some best practice recommendations in this area..

Comment: I would personally rely on a acknowledged majority write to a replica set for this with journal turned off I think

Comment: Though it is normally better, if you can, to encrypt the contents so that you can house a journal and deletion is meaningless on your system

Comment: Thanks for your comments and response. I was expecting that since mongo defaults to journal enabled, there would be a clean "official" solution to have the ability to delete all content. Is there any other forum that I should post this  question to?

Comment: Maybe mongodb-user google group but they will probably say the same thing